# Modifier Keys not working, Keyboard works but not recognized

Tags: synergy

When using Synergy between my Windows PC and a Mac Mini I used to be able to go into system prefs on my Mac Mini and change the modifier keys so that my windows keyboard when on the Mac side would recognize <kbd>alt</kbd> as <kbd>cmd</kbd>.

With the latest updates to mac and synergy this no longer seems to work. I have no keyboard to select from in the drop down where before it was a default keyboard.

When I change the setting and hit apply in mac sys prefs the setting just auto reverts back to not working.

When I try to change the modifier keys in synergy on the configure server screen they seem to do nothing. I tried them all every which way and nothing was changed by those settings on the mac side of my server.

My setup:

**Windows PC (Host):** Windows 8.1

**Mac (Client):** Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Not using auto connect.

Everything seeems to work fine except the modifier keys.

Comment: Having the same issue. I believe I was running 1.4.x before between a Windows 7 and OSX 10.9.5 machine, I would swap Ctrl with Cmd. Upgraded to 1.6 and now getting the same issue as above. (My clipboard also seems to be wonky though)